# Redirect my domain to URL

Tags: domain, url, domain-name

I want to redirect my domain for example.com to a URL like http://www.jotform.me/form/3xxxxxxxxx8 .

I don't have any host I just have a domain.

How could I do it?

Comment: What Web server are you using? Do you want to do it in a specific app? Programming language used? Please consider adding some more details in your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well there are a couple ways you could do this. If you purchased your domain from a registrar you can put forwarding rules against it. This would depend on the registrar you use.

You could also do this with a script if you want. A method could be to make an index.php file on www.example.com with something like:

`<?php
header ('Location: http://www.redirecttohere.com');
?>`

So when someone visits www.example.com your index script will kick in and redirect them to whichever URL you specify.

*EDIT:* You say you don't have any host. If you don't have a web server which your website is pointing at then obviosuly you have no place to load scripts. You would have to do this through your registrar.

Answer (score 0):

A domain points to an IP address, which you can change to anything you want. Alternatively, you can make a domain point to another domain. In order to point to a specific page on a website, you need a hostingprovider and a script. If that website will automatically navigate to that specific page when it is being called from the domain level (example: http://site.example.com will automatically load http://example.com/site/index.php), then you can add a CNAME entry for your domain and point it to site.example.com.

Note that when people visit www.mydomain.com, they will see their browser change to site.example.com and then to example.com/site/index.php.

If you only want to do this for yourself, not for others, you can simply edit your hostsfile, and you don't even need to own the domain, but its unlikely that you want this. I only mention it for the sake of being thorough.

So what you need to do is access the control panel of your domain to set the settings, or if you don't have any, contact the person who has registered your domain and ask them to set it for you. Your domain registrar can always help you making these changes.

Answer (score 0):

You cant do this if you don't have a web-hosting service.

### Domain name redirection

If you have a domain (e.g. `example.com`), usually the domain service provides a control panel where you can associate an IP_address with, for example, `www.example.com`.

However the web-server at that IP address is probably a shared web-server that supports multiple domains and so it looks for a "HOST" header in the HTTP data to decide which website to serve up. A web-browser will put `HOST: www.example.com` rather than `HOST: www.jotform.me` that you want. So this is insufficient.

### URL path addition

To redirect from `www.example.com` to `www.jotform.me/something` requires a web-server to issue a redirection response that includes the `/something`.

Answer (score 0):

My answer depends on whether you can set DNS for the domain yourself in the admin panel of the provider of the domain.

As someone here suggested, you can use a CNAME to redirect the domain to another domain. That probably won't work, as you want to redirect to a specific page or path on that domain. In that case, you want to use the URL setting in the DNS admin. This will redirect your domain to a specific URL.

Maybe your domain host even provides CURL. This creates a solution where you see your domain name in the address bar of the browser, but underneath the page you redirect to is loaded. This is done using an iframe, probably depending on javascript. I wouldn't use it, but for some solutions it might work out and just do what you want.

This solution doesn't require PHP or any other language. Those solutions won't work for you, because they require hosting!

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to do this:

1. Using cPanel

In your cPanel, click the option called **redirects**, which is located under the Domains section. Then, you will reach the domain redirect configuration page. Simply add your settings here.

2. Using .htaccess

Simply add this like to the .htaccess file:

```
Redirect / http://www.mynewwebsite.com/
```

Then, just upload it to your server. If your server uses cPanel, you have to place this file inside the `/public_html` folder.

[Source](https://www.copahost.com/blog/how-to-redirect-a-domain/)